# How to save a Preview session with multiple pdf files open?

Tags: pdf, preview

I often work with multiple pdf files open in Preview. I would like to save the "session", so that I can go back to that exact set of files and work with them again. Is there a way to do that?

In most browsers this is standard, but I don't see any way to do it in Preview, or any other pdf viewer. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences -> general, and uncheck "close windows when quitting". Now whichever session you want to preserve, just quit the app with that. When you reopen preview, all those files load too.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to use Preview to look at different pdf files in the meantime. So simply closing the app won't work-- I need to be able to save the information about what's open.

Comment: @hub as it was in the deleted comment, Open recent is the closest  to your goal, that I know of. We can wait for more answers and you can edit this summary in the question. :)